# How to package a program that has no makefile?

Tags: package, deb

I'm creating a Debian package for a piece of software that has no usable makefile at all. Should I put the building instructions into `debian/rules` or a separate Makefile? I'm tending towards the latter.

If I do create a separate Makefile, how do I properly include it in my source package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's any actual *building* commands (rather than simply installation) to do, my instinct would be to treat the lack of a makefile infrastructure as a bug in the upstream distribution and patch it by providing a makefile in the Debian diff like I'd fix any other upstream bug. Be sure to feed your fix upstream.

However, if it just a matter of running a number of `cp` commands to get the various parts of the software into the right locations in the file system when building the package, then I'd just put those in `debian/rules`.

Comment: The distribution does include `.vcproj` files. That's what I meant by "not usable".

Comment: @Erik: I'd still consider it a bug/deficiency that it doesn't come with a build infrastructure that can be used with a free toolchain. The upstream author may or may not agree with that, but it wouldn't change how I'd handle the lack of makefile in the packaging process.